# What is the importance of disjoint edges in k-opt algorithms?

Tags: heuristics, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to implement a k-opt algorithm and I'm bogged down on a detail: the importance of choosing disjoint edges.

My question: Is there any benefit to considering adjacent edges, or is the full power of the heuristic achieved when only disjoint edges are considered?

Wikipedia seems confused on this question. [Its description of k-opt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms) explicitly says "k mutually disjoint edges", but then it describes 2-opt and 2.5-opt as special cases of k-opt, and describes both those algorithms as processing adjacent edges. Is there something I'm not understanding here?

Comment: What's a k-opt algorithm? What problem is it intended to solve? Can you provide some background?

Comment: in the 2-opt case, if you remove 2 adjacent edges, say (A,B) and (B,C), that makes no sense, because they can only be replaced by the same edges, there is only one edge from A to B and only one edge from C to B. You should check the 2-opt again.

Comment: 2-opt is described by the following picture. The edges are definitely not adjacent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#/media/File:Showing_a_step_of_the_two-opt_heuristic.png

Comment: assume you take only a subpath k consecutive edges of the current path. then this is a rather local kind of optimization.

Comment: @miracle173 What you say about 2-opt makes perfect sense. However, the pseudo-code illustrating 2-opt at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt defines the edge swap by Nodes i and k, where k may equal i+1. Doesn't that imply adjacent edges?

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer to my own question. I believe there is a benefit to considering adjacent edges. The full power of the heuristic is not achieved when only disjoint edges are considered.

To arrive at this conclusion, I implemented two versions of the 4-opt algorithm in C#. One version considers only disjoint edges and the other considers both disjoint and adjacent edges. Then, I used both algorithms to solve the Travelling Salesman problem for 1000 scenarios of 25 nodes each.

The two algorithms found the same solution 52.7% of the time.
The disjoint+adjacent algorithm found a better solution than the disjoint-only algorithm 45.7% of the time.
The disjoint-only algorithm found a better solution than the disjoint+adjacent algorithm 1.6% of the time.

The disjoint+adjacent algorithm found tours that were, on average, 99.1% of the length of the tours found by the disjoint-only algorithm.

Based on these results, I'm fairly confident that there is a benefit to exploring adjacent edges in the k-opt algorithm.

I call this a partial answer because I'm not yet clear on whether it is efficient to explore adjacent edges. Yes, exploring adjacent edges in my experiment improved the tour length by an average of 0.9%, but perhaps I could have improved the tour length more than that by using the same computing effort exploring some 5-opt steps instead.

My experimentation suggests that it is optimal to first explore 2-opt steps, then to explore 3-opt steps that include adjacent edges, then to explore 3-opt steps that include no adjacent edges, then to explore 4-opt steps that include adjacent edges, then to explore 4-opt steps that include no adjacent edges, etc. However, that is preliminary speculation. If anyone knows of k-opt documentation that covers this level of detail, please let me know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the k edges must bu non-connected. k-opt aims to cut a tour (in the Traveling Salesman case) into k parts by removing k edges and then reconnect these parts so that the output is a tour different from the first one and must be **feasible**.

Let's take the example of 2-opt and the following tour *T: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]*.
One of the possibilities is to cut the tour from the edges (2,3)&(6,7) and connect (2) with (6) and (3) with (7), the obtained tour will be *[1,2,6,5,4,3,7,8,9,10]*.
Choosing for example (2,3)&(3,4) will lead to an infeasible tour: the two edges must be composed by four different nodes/cities.

Comment: There are examples involving adjacent edges in which it is possible to reconnect the parts so that the output is a tour different from the first one and feasible. For instance, 3-opt with edges (2,3), (3,4), and (4,5) can be reconnected as (2,4), (4,3), and (3,5). Thus, your conclusion that the edges must be non-connected does not follow from your assertion about the aim of k-opt.

Comment: @Lork Just read again the definition I gave: "to cut a tour into k parts... and then reconnect **these parts**..." not to reconnect the removed edges.  It makes no sense to reconnect the removed edges since the aim of k-opt moves is to obtain a new tour (very) **different** from the input tour.

Comment: Are you claiming that a new tour different from the input tour cannot be created by any k-opt step that includes adjacent edges?

Comment: Yes! The example you exposed in the first comment is giving a feasible tour... But this is not a 3-Opt move. I invite you to heck this paper (On the exact number of possibilities for cutting and reconnecting the tour of a traveling salesman with Lin-k-Opts) and prepare a small example to compare the number of possibilities for cutting the tour that you think there are and what the paper gave.